# Allowing only numbers from paste without using input number in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Before you read furtherly, look at my answer and Priyal Pithadiya answer for two different methods on how you can do this.

I have a client that is not satisfied with the solution I got from yesterdays answer on here. Basically I have this script that prevents non number characters from being inserted in an `input`. It works perfectly when you type but I have a problem here I cannot figure out how to prevent non numbers from being pasted in.

My client has stated that he want to avoid using `input number` since that was the solution that was offered here but for personal reasons he said he needs to use `input text`.

If I have to change my code to get a result like this I will.

Please note, I cannot use jQuery, my solution must be javascript only.

This is my code:

```js
//Prevent non numbers from keypress 
document.querySelector('#numbers-only').addEventListener('keypress',preventNonNumbersInInput);

function preventNonNumbersInInput(event){

  var characters = String.fromCharCode(event.which);

  if(!(/[0-9]/.test(characters))){
    event.preventDefault();
  }

}

//Prevent non numbers from being pasted only numbers can be pasted
document.querySelector('#numbers-only').addEventListener('paste',pasteTest);
function pasteTest(){
  //???
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id='numbers-only'>
```

Comment: Just use `input` event instead of `keypress` event, that takes care of all possible entering methods, including dropping and pasting. That would need a bit different approach to modify an illegal value, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@ try with given solution ,

```js
  document.querySelector('#numbers-only').addEventListener('keypress',preventNonNumbersInInput);
   function preventNonNumbersInInput(event){
  var characters = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
  if(!(/[0-9]/.test(characters))){
   event.preventDefault();
  }
   }
   
   document.querySelector('#numbers-only').addEventListener('paste',pasteTest);
   function pasteTest(event){
    window.setTimeout(() => {
   var characters =event.target.value;
   window.setTimeout(() => {
   if(!(/^\d+$/.test(characters))){
    event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    }
   });
    });
   }
```

```html
 <input type="text" id="numbers-only"  >
```

Comment: I can not use jquery I have to use pure js that's what the client said :(

Comment: Thanks Priyal Pithadiya for your response again and ok

Comment: Sorry about this but how can I do this with a .addEventListener('paste' instead of onpaste="myFunction(this);"  I know that's strange but he likes the code to make use of addEventListener there's a reason why for that which he said is personal just saying I tried to use something like that in the input tag and he said you must make use of addEventListeners in this project. I tried to edit your code with an event listener triggering myFunction

Comment: Priyal Pithadiya I sent him the code and I knew he was going to say something about what I said he said that myFunction must be triggered by an event listener for this project  I tried to convince him but he said you can not use onpaste="myFunction(this);" for this project I know it's strange but change it where it is trigger by an event Listener instead so what I'm I doing wrong now this is what i'm doing document.querySelector('#numbers-only').addEventListener('paste',myFunction); but it is not working with a event listener.

Comment: told them to refer [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/paste)

Comment: A new problem is now showing this in the console with your suggestion of that article Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Comment: then you need to give your full html page access coz with simple html it works fine without any console error, :)

Comment: Sorry Priyal Pithadiya I can not figure this out even with that article you have suggested and the advice that you have given.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172673/discussion-between-priyal-pithadiya-and-fsofb).

Comment: Priyal Pithadiya if you can give me a code example with an event listener I will award you as the best answer sorry I'm tying to do this by my self but i'm getting confused but I am trying tho and ok let us take this to the discussion chat then I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks Priyal Pithadiya for everything because of you I learned a lot today thanks. :-) and my client loves this he said this is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

in-line js:

```html
<input type="text" pattern="\d{1,}" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [onpaste](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onpaste.asp) Event if you want.

```
<input type="text" id='numbers-only' onchange="removeChars()">

function removeChars() {
  var input = document.getElementById('numbers-only');
  input.value = input.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
}
```

Comment: FewFlyBy thanks for your response but the code example did not work it acted like a solution was never provided :(. it still lets me paste letters.

Comment: can you share your fiddle link?

Comment: No it is not working :( is there suppose to be a var before let input?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Priyal Pithadiya for your help I will like to post two versions of Priyal Pithadiya examples from earlier and now which includes two versions one is with

a onpaste example and the other one is based on using an addEventListener by paste this is for any future readers reading this. All credit goes to Priyal Pithadiya.

***With onpaste***

```js
 document.querySelector('#numbers-only').addEventListener('keypress',preventNonNumbersInInput);
  function preventNonNumbersInInput(event){
    var characters = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
    if(!(/[0-9]/.test(characters))){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
  function myFunction(e) {
        var el = e;
        setTimeout(function() {
            el.value = el.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
        }, 0);
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="numbers-only" onpaste="myFunction(this);" >
```

***With a event listener***

```js
  document.querySelector('#numbers-only').addEventListener('keypress',preventNonNumbersInInput);
   function preventNonNumbersInInput(event){
  var characters = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
  if(!(/[0-9]/.test(characters))){
   event.preventDefault();
  }
   }
   
   document.querySelector('#numbers-only').addEventListener('paste',pasteTest);
   function pasteTest(event){
    window.setTimeout(() => {
   var characters =event.target.value;
   window.setTimeout(() => {
   if(!(/^\d+$/.test(characters))){
    event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    }
   });
    });
   }
```

```html
 <input type="text" id="numbers-only"  >
```